# What model should I use to find coordinate locations of objects on an image (not bounding boxes)

Tags: neural-networks, computer-vision, training, python

I am developing a neural network to count pits on an etched crystal wafer, and I created a dataset by placing points on each pit.

Each line in my annotation file looks like this:

Id, Filepath, Coordinates
965,822.jpg,"[{""x"": 2, ""y"": 439}, {""x"": 50, ""y"": 384}, {""x"": 130, ""y"": 454}, {""x"": 177, ""y"": 396}, {""x"": 261, ""y"": 429}, {""x"": 251, ""y"": 529}, {""x"": 272, ""y"": 351}, {""x"": 475, ""y"": 407}, {""x"": 481, ""y"": 313}, {""x"": 492, ""y"": 231}, {""x"": 511, ""y"": 138}, {""x"": 427, ""y"": 111}, {""x"": 335, ""y"": 98}, {""x"": 489, ""y"": 82}, {""x"": 436, ""y"": 71}, {""x"": 399, ""y"": 56}, {""x"": 366, ""y"": 55}, {""x"": 325, ""y"": 49}, {""x"": 278, ""y"": 44}, {""x"": 237, ""y"": 28}, {""x"": 190, ""y"": 15}, {""x"": 398, ""y"": 15}, {""x"": 421, ""y"": 29}, {""x"": 513, ""y"": 31}, {""x"": 131, ""y"": 17}, {""x"": 54, ""y"": 5}]"

All of the models I've tried using only work with bounding boxes, and I'm not experienced enough to adapt them to work with points.

Is there a model that I can use that works with points by default? Or just an easy way to do this. I'm planning on using pytorch, but I would be open to other implementations.

Comment: You can try segmentation and ask to predict a heatmap. Or if you have a fixed number of points on each image, you can try regression of the coordinates directly.